# Laravel 7 internal server error 500 when sending email

Tags: php, laravel, mailing

I'm having some trouble with sending email using laravel. I've looked around the stackoverflow for solutions but none worked so far. Here's my env and code so far.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail.gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_SETUP=false

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=myemail.gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Namehere"
```

and this is my mail.php file

```
'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.googlemail.com'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],

  'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'myemail@gmail.com'),
],
```

Now this is my code. It's just a simple to test the email function. This is the class created in mail folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewTicketMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public $details;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->$details;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Mail from ')->view('emails.new_ticket_mail');
}
}
```

and this is the route called

```
Route::get('send-email', function(){
$details = [
    'title'=> 'New Ticket Received',
    'body' => 'We have received your ticket and will process it. Please do not reply to this 
   email'
];

 \Mail::to('receiver@gmail.com')->send(new \App\Mail\NewTicketMail($details));
return view('emails.thanks');
});
```

the route works if i commented out the Mail to line. any suggestions? I've been at it for hours.

Comment: Check your server log to find out the reason for the 500. The Laravel logs are found in `storage/logs`

Comment: I've checked it, there is no mention of error 500 oddly.

Comment: There's no information at all in the Laravel logs when that error occurs?

Comment: I've changed the app debug to true now and im getting the ErrorException
Array to string conversion instead

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message you are facing, and your attempts to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mail class you are accessing a properties property which does not exist.

Rather in your mailable constructor do something like

```
public function __construct($details){
    $this->details = $details;
}
```

This is for sure one issue. As laravel will throw an unknown property error.

P.s. make sure your env has debug as true if you are not seeing errors in your logs.

Comment: Okay i have changed the debug to true and im getting the ErrorException
Array to string conversion error now. I also changed the details thing but still the array error

Comment: Nvm your solution was the correct one. I didnt realise that after this-> there is no dollar sign. Thanks!